# Thread safety - reading mutable objects (java)

Tags: java, thread-safety, readonly

I have a shared resource - a simple POJO wrapping a HashMap - that will be initialised once at startup and then only ever read, possibly simultaneously, by many threads (context is a web application). Do I need to synchronise access to the object (or alternatively use a concurrent hashap) or is safe to have multiple simultaneous reads? Will synchronizing add significant overhead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip synchronization for the read access to that map if you make sure that all writes *happen-before* all reads. What it means is described in [JLS 7 chapter 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5).

In practice, you will have to make sure that the `HashMap` is populated before any other threads that will access it are started and that its contents are not modified after that.

The reason this solution will work is that `Thread.start()` call enforces a synchronization and therefore guarantees that all changes made prior to that call will be visible to both old and new threads after that call. Should you modify the object after that call this guarantee would be lost and a synchronized access would be necessary.

Comment: It sounds simpler than it is. In this case you would use the fact that the call to `otherThread.start()` guarantees that any modification prior to that call are visible to `otherThread`. You would loose that guarantee if you pass a reference to the map to an already running thread in some unsynchronized way (AFAIK http://pastebin.com/p3mpbNxv should have that problem.) Code doing it in the right order does not guarantee that it actually happens in that order unless you do something that guarantees such a happens-before relation.

Comment: @zapl I pointed to JLS and shown a simple practical solution. I know what happens behind the scenes, the author of this question may either learn for himself from the given JLS chapter or take what I wrote for granted. Either way, in this case, he'll be good.

Comment: Reason of the comment was that I felt that the crucial point in your 2nd paragraph is hard to see if you don't know it already. So it was more or less directed at readers / hint for you how you could IMO improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure all you will need is to perform read operations you do not need synchronization. This is also the same reason there are different locks - read and write in [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

> A ReadWriteLock maintains a pair of associated locks, one for read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.

As you have no writers there is no need for synchronizing.

Answer (score 1):

As the results of multiple reads do not depend on the sequence of events, I would say you don't encounter race conditions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and it is therefore not necessary to synchronize access.